# C: printf (with fork())

Tags: c

In the next code:

```
int i = 1;
fork();
i=i*2;
fork();
i=i*2;
fork();
i=i*2;

printf("%d\n", i);
```

Why `8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8` is printed, and not `1,2,2,4,4,8,8,8`? fork() duplicate the process, and print the i before each fork. What I miss?

Comment: Every single process will be doing the same exact operations on `i`.  You will see the same values for each at the end.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like
printf("%d\n", i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the code shown, you should be seeing eight lots of 6 (you wrote `i = i + 2;` instead of `i = i * 2;` for the last computation.

Since each process follows the same code path, each process will produce the same result.

To get the result you expected, you'd have to track whether each `fork()` yielded the parent or child process:

```
int i = 1;
if (fork())
{
    i=i*2;
    if (fork())
    {
        i=i*2;
        if (fork())
            i=i*2;    // + --> *
    }
}
printf(|%d\n", i);
```

I'm assuming there are no problems with the `fork()` operation.  It is also interesting to note that you could invert any or all of the conditions and end up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Because fork continues to execute the code as it goes downwards.  So each of the processes will run through the i = i * 2 each time as they spawn off more children.  Making it what you get and not what you expected (i.e. it doesn't jump to the end of the block once forked).

Info on fork: http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html

Answer (score 0):

Each new process gets a copy of the stack of the parent, so immediately after calling fork(), both parent and child have the same value for i -- but they don't have the *same* stack, just a copy... so changing i's value in one process has no effect on the other.

If you want two parallel pieces of code to share the same memory, either use threads (and memory that's in the heap, not on the stack), or use an explicit shared memory region.